# css not computing all on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a website for a friend and I am trying to add a responsive nav bar. The one that I have here:

https://jsfiddle.net/99ycpLzs/2/

```
<ul class="topnav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About the Coaches</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How to Join</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PIH</a></li>
            <li class="icon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

works great on desktop, but once on mobile (such as iPhone) it does not show any of the styles.

```
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #C62828;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover :not(.icon) {background-color: #111;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is little conflict, It won't automatic run in mobile, you must click on the Icon to transform to mobile style.

If you want it automatic run in mobile you must remove . responsive in this part

```css
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav{position: relative;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great on the mobile. The only problem is that the button to expand the menu doesn't open it.

Comment: I have just found out your problems/n
https://jsfiddle.net/99ycpLzs/4/
Your problem is (: first-child) must be (:first-child) non-space it works